# JAMstack SSG + Angular...can we have parts of a page statically generated and part of the page be dynamic?

Tags: angular, hugo, jamstack

I'm researching [Jamstack](https://jamstack.org/) and SSG's (Static Site Generator) such as [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/documentation/) and [Scully](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2019/12/16/introducing-scully-the-angular-static-site-generator/) to use with our Angular SPA to decrease file sizes and to speed up loading.

All the examples that I have seen generate pages that don't have dynamic content. There is interactivity, such as [search](https://blog.jeremylikness.com/blog/dynamic-search-in-a-static-hugo-website/), etc. but not user customized content.

We have parts of our website that can be totally statically generated. However, other parts of the website have static pages with portions of the page that are customized for the user. Imagine a product page with recommendations for the user.  The product info is pretty much static but the recommendations are dynamic.

How do we create/architect something like this?  Can SSG's be configured for this?

Answer (score 1):

With the JAMstack, you can most definitely have a static site with dynamic elements like personalization. The CDN has advanced a lot in the last couple of years and you can now run a lot of functionality (like personalization and authentication) at the edge without the need for the extra round trip to the server. You can also extend a lot of this functionality, so you can ping serverless functions to dynamically hydrate your site's content as needed.

For personalization specifically, many CDN providers like Netlify offer internationalization and A/B testing functionality at the CDN level, so you can easily serve different pieces of content based on a user's geographic location or role.